# Blink Element’s Border the CSS way

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get my CSS border to blink like what was demonstrated in this link: (http://www.multipetros.gr/posts/728-blink-elements-border-the-css-way).

However, I can't seem to get it to work on my website. Could someone help me out?

Thank you.

**My CSS code:**

```
.cover-buttons > ul > li:nth-last-child(5) a {
  color: black;
  /*border: 1px solid black;*/
  padding: 14px 18px!important;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 17px;
  font-size: 12px;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: all .2s ease;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  list-style-type: none;
  font-family: 'Varela Round', 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

@keyframes blink2 { 
   50% { border-color: coral; } 
}
.cover-buttons > ul > li:nth-last-child(5) a {
    animation: blink2 .5s step-end infinite alternate;
}
```

**JS Fiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/75nvLs4x/24/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are only defining `border-color`, you need to define `border-width` and `border-style` as well, `border:1px solid red;`

Setting border to `.cover-buttons>ul>li:nth-last-child(5) a` would be much better

```js
var href2 = jQuery('.buttons.medium.button-outlined').not('.add-review, .bookmark, .show-dropdown, .sn-share').html();
var link2 = "<a href='" + href2 + "' target='_blank'>Click Here</a>";
jQuery('.buttons.medium.button-outlined').not('.add-review, .bookmark, .show-dropdown, .sn-share').replaceWith(link2);
```

```css
.cover-buttons>ul>li:nth-last-child(5) a {
  color: black;
  /*border: 1px solid black;*/
  padding: 14px 18px!important;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 17px;
  font-size: 12px;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: all .2s ease;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  list-style-type: none;
  font-family: 'Varela Round', 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

.cover-buttons>ul>li:nth-last-child(5) a {
  animation: blink2 .5s step-end infinite alternate;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}

@keyframes blink2 {
  50% {
    border-color: red;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="profile-cover-content reveal">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="cover-buttons">
      <ul v-pre>
        <li>
          <div class="inside-rating listing-rating button-plain">
            <span class="value">7</span>
            <sup class="out-of">/10</sup>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>

          <div class="buttons medium button-outlined ">
            https://www.hotmail.com </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#add-review" class="buttons button-outlined medium add-review c27-add-listing-review">
            <i class="mi chat_bubble_outline"></i><span class="button-label">Add a comment</span> </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" data-listing-id="211" data-nonce="82e82078c5" class="buttons button-outlined medium bookmark c27-bookmark-button ">
            <i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i><span class="button-label">Bookmark</span> </a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="buttons button-outlined medium show-dropdown sn-share" type="button" id="5a4491c30a4b9__cover_button" data-toggle="dropdown">
            <i class="mi redo"></i><span class="button-label"></span> </a>
          <ul class="i-dropdown share-options dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="5a4491c30a4b9__cover_button">
            <li><a class="c27-open-popup-window" href="http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fsloth.com%2Flisting%2Foffer-test%2F&amp;title=Offer+test&amp;picture=http%3A%2F%2Fsloth.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2017%2F10%2Flogo.png">Facebook</a></li>
            <li><a class="c27-open-popup-window" href="http://twitter.com/home?status=Offer+test+http%3A%2F%2Fsloth.com%2Flisting%2Foffer-test%2F">Twitter</a></li>
            <li><a class="c27-open-popup-window" href="https://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fsloth.com%2Flisting%2Foffer-test%2F&amp;media=http%3A%2F%2Fsloth.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2017%2F10%2Flogo.png&amp;description=Offer+test">Pinterest</a></li>
            <li><a class="c27-open-popup-window" href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=http%3A%2F%2Fsloth.com%2Flisting%2Foffer-test%2F">Google Plus</a></li>
            <li><a class="c27-open-popup-window" href="http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&amp;url=http%3A%2F%2Fsloth.com%2Flisting%2Foffer-test%2F&amp;title=Offer+test">LinkedIn</a></li>
            <li><a class="c27-open-popup-window" href="http://www.tumblr.com/share?v=3&amp;u=http%3A%2F%2Fsloth.com%2Flisting%2Foffer-test%2F&amp;t=Offer+test">Tumblr</a></li>
            <li><a href="mailto:?subject=http%3A%2F%2Fsloth.com%2Flisting%2Foffer-test%2F&amp;body=Offer test - http%3A%2F%2Fsloth.com%2Flisting%2Foffer-test%2F">Mail</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="buttons button-outlined medium show-dropdown c27-listing-actions" type="button" id="more-actions" data-toggle="dropdown">
            <i class="mi more_vert"></i>
          </a>
          <ul class="i-dropdown share-options dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="more-actions">
            <li><a href="http://sloth.com/my-account/my-listings/?action=edit&#038;job_id=211">Edit Listing</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#report-listing-modal">Report this Listing</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No scripts needed here.

Comment: It was in OP's jsfiddle, still this is not a valid reason to downvote any answer, you could comment to improve the answer

Comment: If you can see the fiddle, the link `click here` is adding by JS, so if I remove js the link won't be available.

Answer (score 2):

The problem occurs because the border style and border width are not specified for animated border. Just add following property into your last CSS rule:

```
border: 4px solid;
```

You could also set other initial width, color or transparent of animated border using the [border properties](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_border.asp).

Comment: Many thanks for helping me out Alexander. However, Abhishek Pandey responded earlier.

Comment: @firefirehelphelp , and his answer is more detailed! ;)